# Conver Mixed-Length 1 level deep list to data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list as follows:

```
$A
[1] "one"
$B
[1] "Two"
$C
[1] "Three"
$D
[1] "Four" "Five"    
$E
[1] "Six" "Seven"
```

And in the end I want to get a data frame like this:

```
Var1    Var2
A       One
B       Two
C       Three
D       Four
D       Five
E       Six
E       Seven
```

Number of items in a list element can be any (potentially, also `character(0)`. Nesting level is only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
x <- list(A = "one", 
          B = "Two", 
          c = "Three", 
          D = c("Four", "Five"), 
          E = c("Six", "Seven"))

df <- data.frame(Var1 = rep(names(x), sapply(x, length)),
                 Var2 = unlist(x, use.names = F))
```